# Python: Why will this string print but not write to a file?

Tags: python, html, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I am new to Python and working on a utility that changes an XML file into an HTML. The XML comes from a call to `request = urllib2.Request(url)`, where I generate the custom url earlier in the code, and then set `response = urllib2.urlopen(request)` and, finally, `xml_response = response.read()`. This works okay, as far as I can tell.

My trouble is with parsing the response. For starters, here is a partial example of the XML structure I get back:

[image]

I tried adapting the slideshow example in the minidom tutorial here to parse my XML (which is ebay search results, by the way): http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html

My code so far looks like this, with try blocks as an attempt to diagnose issues:

```
doc = minidom.parseString(xml_response)

  #Extract relevant information and prepare it for HTML formatting.
  try: 
    handleDocument(doc)
  except:
    print "Failed to handle document!" 

def getText(nodelist):  #taken straight from slideshow example 
  rc = []
  for node in nodelist:
    if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
      print "A TEXT NODE!" 
      rc.append(node.data)
  return ''.join(rc)       #this is a string, right?

def handleDocument(doc): 
  outputFile = open("EbaySearchResults.html", "w")
  outputFile.write("<html>\n")
  outputFile.write("<body>\n")
  try:
    items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item") 
  except:
    "Failed to get elements by tag name." 
  handleItems(items)
  outputFile.write("</html>\n")
  outputFile.write("</body>\n") 

def handleItems(items):
  for item in items:    
    title = item.getElementsByTagName("title")[0] #there should be only one title

    print "<h2>%s</h2>" % getText(title.childNodes) #this works fine!

    try: #none of these things work!
      outputFile.write("<h2>%s</h2>" % getText(title.childNodes))

      #outputFile.write("<h2>" + getText(title.childNodes) + "</h2>")

      #str = getText(title.childNodes) 
      #outputFIle.write(string(str)) 
      #outputFile.write(getText(title.childNodes))  

    except:
      print "FAIL"
```

I do not understand why the correct title text does print to the console but throws an exception and does not work for the output file. Writing plain strings like this works fine: `outputFile.write("<html>\n")` What is going on with my string construction? As far as I can tell, the `getText` method I am using from the minidom example returns a string--which is just the sort of thing you can write to a file..?

Comment: *What* exception? Please post the full error message including the stack trace.

Comment: Why is it that so many questions here just say 'an exception', or give the message without the stack trace - that is really useful debugging information, why would anyone *not* include it? It boggles me.

Comment: I suppose we just think that our mistakes will be blaringly obvious to expert programmers. But you are right--upon learning how to print the stack trace and finding that it simply said, `NameError: global name 'outputFile' is not defined`, I was instantly able to see the problem. Lesson learned. :-)

Comment: @nicole: Expert programmers make silly mistakes just like that one all the time; the only real advantage we have is that, having made them so many times, we know how to quickly find the problem from the stack trace. :)

Comment: I get the impression that many novice programmers, since they don't always understand the stack trace, assume it is meaningless and just ignore it!

Comment: What's sad is that I'm only new to Python...not to programming in general. Shame on me. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I print the actual stack trace...

```
...
      except:
        print "Exception when trying to write to file:"
        print '-'*60
        traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
        print '-'*60
        traceback.print_tb(sys.last_traceback)
...
```

...I will instantly see the problem:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tohtml.py", line 85, in handleItems
    outputFile.write(getText(title.childNodes))
NameError: global name 'outputFile' is not defined
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Looks like something has gone out of scope!

Fellow beginners, take note.

Comment: As a note, if you don't handle an exception, it will automatically print the stack trace and error for you. Generally, you should only ever catch exact exceptions you are expecting to come up and know how to deal with, otherwise, let it come to the front so you can see why it occurred and fix it (either by handling the exception correctly, or stopping it from ever happening).